# edit dropDown list field in material table reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-table

i have the following code,

```html
class AdminPanel extends Component {
  state = {
    idProject: ''
  }
  columns = [

    { title: 'Projet Prod', field: 'name', editable: 'never' },
    {
      title: 'Projet Preprod', field: 'project',editable: true, render:  rowData =>
        rowData.preprodName === '' ?
          <Select projectPreprod={this.props.preprodProjects} onSelectProject={this.handleSelectedProject} />
          :
          <Label>{rowData.preprodName}</Label>
    },
  ]

  handleSelectedProject = (idProjectValue) => {
    this.setState({ idProject: idProjectValue }, function () {
      console.log(this.state.idProject);
    });
  }

  render() {
    let projectsTableData = [];
    for (let key in this.props.projects) {
      projectsTableData.push({
        ...this.props.projects[key],
      });
    }
    let projects = (<MaterialTable
      title="Gestion des projets"
      columns={this.columns}
      data={projectsTableData}
      LoadingComponent={Spinner}
      editable={{
        
       onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>

          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              {
                let data = [...projectsTableData.project];
                let index = data.indexOf(oldData);
                data[index] = { ...newData };
                this.handleUpdate(newData.id, newData, data);
              }
              resolve()
            }, 1000)
          }),
      }}
      
    />);
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={10} md={{ offset: 2 }}>
            {projects}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

i want to edit the project field the probleme is i have a conditional rendering so when i want to edit it and  have rowData.preprodName !== '' it renders a label not the select and i want to edit the data in the select,, 
Can anyone help me please?